# Using RxJs map to convert one type of array to another type of array

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my **Angular** application I use **HttpClient** to get **json** data from server. However, I need to do some conversion to the returned data at the client-side.

So I try to convert an array of **Type A** returned from the server to an array of **Type B** with the following code snippet.

```
this.http.get<any[]>(this.env.accounts.url.accountTypes).pipe(map(e => {
    console.log(e); // print the retuned array not a single item
    return {'label': e.name, 'value': e.id}
  }
)).subscribe(data => {
  this.accountTypes = data;
  console.log(this.accountTypes); // prints {label: undefined, value: undefined}
});
```

I must be doing this wrong, but I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

The server returns an array like:

```
[
  {name: "Name 1", id: 1},
  {name: "Name 2", id: 2},
  {name: "Name 3", id: 3},
]
```

And I need to convert it into the following format

```
[
  {label: "Name 1", value: 1},
  {label: "Name 2", value: 2},
  {label: "Name 3", value: 3},
]
```

Can somebody please point out what is wrong in my code and how to fix it.

Comment: As you correctly noticed e is an Array and not a single item. With e.name and e.id you are trying to return name and id of the array! You need to map the content of the array too.

Comment: @NicholasK, of course, I know AnguarJs is predecessor o  Angular and have a number of differences. But I don't understand what tags you want me to add here.

Comment: @NicholasK, you are right. I had entered `angularjs` instead of `angular`, he has corrected it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), with RxJS's [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator.

As stated on the RxJS documentation for the map operator, the purpose of Map is to

> Apply projection with each value from source.

What you can do instead, is this:

```js
this.http.get<any[]>(this.env.accounts.url.accountTypes)
  .pipe(
    map(res => {
      // insert logic 
      const data = res.map(obj => ({
        label: obj.name,
        value: obj.id
      }));
      return data;
    })
  )).subscribe(data => {
    this.accountTypes = data;
    console.log(this.accountTypes); // prints {label: undefined, value: undefined}
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comment please also map the array content

```
return e.map(entry => {'label': entry.name, 'value': entry.id});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the data using the map operator:

```
var result = [];
x.map(e => {
  const obj = {};
  obj['label'] = e.name;
  obj['value'] = e.id;
  result.push(obj);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are many solutions but Model Adapter can be a generic solution.

```
// app/core/adapter.ts
export interface Adapter<T> {
    adapt(item: any): T;
}
export class AccountType {
//.....
}
export class AccountAdapter implements Adapter<AccountType> {

    adapt(item: any): AccountType {
        return new AccountType(
            item.id,
          --  item.name,
          ++  item.value,
        );
    }
}


export class AccountService {
    private baseUrl = 'http://api.*';
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private adapter: AccountAdapter,
    ) { }

    list(): Observable<AccountType[]> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/`;
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(
            // Adapt each item in the raw data array
            map((data: any[]) => data.map(item => this.adapter.adapt(item))),
        );
    }
}
```

[this example may help more](https://blog.florimond.dev/consuming-apis-in-angular-the-model-adapter-pattern)